# How to generate multiple files in sequence with data in sequence?

Tags: command-line, bash, files

I have to create 50 files in sequence labelled `r01.inp` to `r50.inp` and in each file I need this text in sequence as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
abc2 r01.inp > r01.log
```

I used echo and touch to create the 50 files with same data but I still have to manually change `r01.inp > r01.log` to match the file name. Is there any way I can generate multiple files and the data inside it is also in a sequence i.e. `r01.inp` has `abc2 r01.inp > r01.log` while `r02.inp` has `abc2 r02.inp > r02.log` in it and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From google [bash loop padded](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+loop+padded) to StackOverflow [How to zero pad a sequence of integers in bash so that all have the same width?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8789815/6532948) I ended up with:

```
for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 1 50)
do
    echo "#!/bin/bash
abc2 r$i.inp > r$i.log" > r$i.inp
done
```

This will produce r01~r50.inp files and each file will contain the `#!/bin/bash` hashbang and the `abc2 r##.inp > r##.log` line as requested.

Comment: You could also use `seq -w 1 50` or just use a bash *brace expansion* `{01..50}`